# SQL query into a table to find the row with the minimal value >= X for a particular column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table called Table1 with column name, colSize. The column colSize holds integers

For an integer X, I want to find the row where the colSize is the minimal value that is greater than or equal to X.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from Table1 where colSize >= X order by colSize limit 1
```

Comment: I think that you need to add: `ORDER BY colSize ASC`

Comment: just add in the ASC after colSize and it worked a treat: 'Select * from Table1 where colSize >= X order by colSize ASC limit 1'